# Create a black and white chessboard in a two dimensional array

Tags: python

Is there a better (and shorter) way of how to create chessboard like array. Requirements for the board are:

- board can be different size (in my example it's 3x3)
- bottom left square of the board should always be black
- black square is presented by `"B"`, white square is presented by `"W"`

**Code that I have:**

```
def isEven(number):
    return number % 2 == 0

board = [["B" for x in range(3)] for x in range(3)]
if isEven(len(board)):
    for rowIndex, row in enumerate(board):
        if isEven(rowIndex + 1):
            for squareIndex, square in enumerate(row):
                if isEven(squareIndex + 1):
                    board[rowIndex][squareIndex] = "W"
        else:
            for squareIndex, square in enumerate(row):
                if not isEven(squareIndex + 1):
                    board[rowIndex][squareIndex] = "W"
else:
    for rowIndex, row in enumerate(board):
        if not isEven(rowIndex + 1):
            for squareIndex, square in enumerate(row):
                if isEven(squareIndex + 1):
                    board[rowIndex][squareIndex] = "W"
        else:
            for squareIndex, square in enumerate(row):
                if not isEven(squareIndex + 1):
                    board[rowIndex][squareIndex] = "W"

for row in board:
    print row
```

**Output:**

```
['B', 'W', 'B']
['W', 'B', 'W']
['B', 'W', 'B']
```

Comment: I'm sure you could have some case using modulus. The color of each position would be based off the row and column number.

Comment: Have you considered making it a flat list, filling in the appropriate value in order, and then reassembling it into a MxN grid?

Comment: IMO, take the up-front hit and use bitboards!--they're strictly superior in terms of everything: memory footprint, computing speed... it lends to more elegant design, too, than nested lists of strings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about:

```
>>> n = 3
>>> board = [["BW"[(i+j+n%2+1) % 2] for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
>>> print board
[['B', 'W', 'B'], ['W', 'B', 'W'], ['B', 'W', 'B']]
>>> n = 4
>>> board = [["BW"[(i+j+n%2+1) % 2] for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]
>>> print board
[['W', 'B', 'W', 'B'], ['B', 'W', 'B', 'W'], ['W', 'B', 'W', 'B'], ['B', 'W', 'B', 'W']]
```

Comment: Why are doing this fancy stuff with indices? `(i + j) % 2` is sufficient.

Comment: @android: no, it's not. If you just use (i + j) % 2, you won't always get that the "bottom left square of the board should always be black", and your reversal trick didn't occur to me.

Comment: @DSM I see it now. I think I just didn't like the look of it inside the comprehension when `n%2+1` could be calculated once before building the list.

Answer (score 2):

Kind of a hack but

```
print [["B" if abs(n - row) % 2 == 0 else "W" for n in xrange(3)] for row in xrange(3)][::-1]
```

This seems like requirements creep or something =)

```
def make_board(n):
    ''' returns an empty list for n <= 0 '''
    return [["B" if abs(c - r) % 2 == 0 else "W" for c in xrange(n)] for r in xrange(n)][::-1]
```

Comment: it doesn't work correctly for n=4, because bottom left corner is not black

Comment: Now it's all right. It would be nice to make it a function - it would be easier to use ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) solution:

```
from itertools import cycle
N = 4

colors = cycle(["W","B"])
row_A  = [colors.next() for _ in xrange(N)]
if not N%2: colors.next()
row_B  = [colors.next() for _ in xrange(N)]

rows = cycle([row_A, row_B])
board = [rows.next() for _ in xrange(N)]
```

For `N=4` this gives

```
['W', 'B', 'W', 'B']
['B', 'W', 'B', 'W']
['W', 'B', 'W', 'B']
['B', 'W', 'B', 'W']
```

This should be extensible to multiple colors (say a board that goes "B", "W", "G") if you make sure to add each new row and cycle to the list of rows.

Comment: The one in bottom left corner should be 'B'

Comment: @piokuc Thanks, fixed. All I had to do is change the start order. Didn't realize up until this point that chess boards had an orientation!

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(board)):
    for j in range(len(board)):
        if isEven(i + j + len(board)):
            board[i][j] = "W"
```

Answer (score 0):

This one correctly sets the bottom left corner to 'B', always:

```
def board(n):
    def line(n, offset):
        return [(i+offset) % 2 and 'W' or 'B' for i in range(n)]
    return [line(n,i) for i in range(n+1,1,-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Brutally easy to understand. Plus, can generate a rectangular board:

```
def gen_board(width, height):
    bw = ['B', 'W']
    l = [[bw[(j + i) % 2] for j in range(width)] for i in range(height)]
    # this is done to make sure B is always bottom left
    # alternatively, you could do the printing in reverse order
    l.reverse()

    ## or, we could ensure B is always bottom left by adjusting the index
    #offset = height%2 + 1
    #l = [[bw[(j + i + offset) % 2] for j in range(width)] for i in range(height)]
    return l

def print_board(b):
    for row in b:
        print row
```

Test drive:

```
>>> print_board(gen_board(4, 3))
['B', 'W', 'B', 'W']
['W', 'B', 'W', 'B']
['B', 'W', 'B', 'W']
```

Answer (score 0):

With one-line numpy code, without for loop:

```
import numpy as np

chessbool = (np.arange(3)[:, None] + np.arange(3)) % 2 == 0
```

and the output is:

```
array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True]]
```

To fill the array with `W` and `B`:

```
chessboard = np.where(chessbool,'B','W')
```

and the output is:

```
array([['B', 'W', 'B'],
       ['W', 'B', 'W'],
       ['B', 'W', 'B']])
```

Comment: Which line is the one line?

Comment: the line `chessbool = (np.arange(3)[:, None] + np.arange(3)) % 2 == 0`. the other lines are to fill of `W` and `B` the boolean array

Comment: with only the first line the output is `array([[ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False],
       [ True, False,  True]])`

Comment: Note that I think you can do `np.where(chessbool,'B','W')`.